# Schema from SchemaRDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

Given a [`SchemaRDD`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD) (loaded using [`SQLContext.parquetFile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext)), how do I extract its metadata/schema/list of columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field list is accessible through the `SchemaRDD` as `[rdd].schema.fields`.

```
lazy val schema: StructType
         Returns the schema of this SchemaRDD (represented by a StructType).
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a `printSchema()` method under `SchemaRDD`, see [SchemaRDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD).